# Can you call xsl:evaluate and retain the context of the results?

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

I am using `xsl:evaluate` to evaluate xpaths. However, the result is different to if I directly evaluate xpaths, because in the latter case I can get access to the ancestors of the results but in the former I can't.

Is there any way to retain information about the context of the results of `<xsl:evaluate>`?

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/one">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="xpath">
        <xsl:text>//three</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="matches1">
        <xsl:evaluate xpath="$xpath" context-item="." />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:for-each select="$matches1/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(parent::*)" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:variable name="matches2" select="//three" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$matches2">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(parent::*)" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the input file:

```
<one>
    <two>
        <three />
        <three />
    </two>
    <two />
</one>
```

and here is the output:

```
one
three,
three,
three,two
three,two
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:variable name="matches1" as="item()*">
    <xsl:evaluate xpath="$xpath" context-item="." />
</xsl:variable>
```

It has really nothing to do with `xsl:evaluate` but rather how `xsl:variable` (and `xsl:param`) work in XSLT 2 and later, mainly due to backwards compatibility as to how things worked in XSLT 1; if you don't provide an `as` attribute you are creating a new document node (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#temporary-trees) that is populated by a copy of the items/nodes returned by the sequence constructor inside, i.e. in your case by the nodes selected/returned by `xsl:evaluate`. If you provide `as="item()*"` (or for your case of nodes you could also use `as="node()*"`) then no new document node is constructed and populated but the variable is rather bound directly to the items/nodes returned by the sequence constructor (i.e. in your case the `xsl:evaluate`) inside.

The gory details are in the XSLT 2 and 3 spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#variable-values and in Michael Kay's XSLT bible https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xslt-20-and/9780470192740/.

Comment: Thank you. Could you briefly explain this please?

Comment: @wrgrs, yes, I have added some explanation, will also later look to add the link(s) to the section in the XSLT 3 spec.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot.